# Add a directory to python path using Canopy (Windows 7 64bit)

Tags: windows, canopy

I am running Canopy 1.5.5 as my default python environment on Windows 7 (64 bit). I have recently made a module, named tools, that was thought to be used in different scripts located in different directories of the system. To do that I would like to add the directory that contains the tools module to my python path. What is the easy why to do that without messing thigs up?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the directory in your PYTHONPATH environment variable. See this article for how to (and when not to) do this:
https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me with Rapid environment Editor.